# How map a collection and single value to function

Tags: python

I have a function invoke_query that takes two arguments (connection (object) and sql_query (string)).  I have a set of queries in a collection  queries = ["queryA", "queryB"].  I want to pass the connection object and each item in queries collection to the function invoke_query.  Is this possible or am i going about it wrong?

```
connector = handlers.helpers.sf_connector.SF_CONNECTOR().get_connector(str(Schemas.PRIVATE))

queries = ["create table A...", "create table B..."]

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(invoke_query, connector, queries)

def invoke_query(connection, sql):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the simple way is best:

```
for sql in queries:
    invoke_query(connection, sql)
```

If you want to work the result, the built-in 'map' does kind of what you want, but first you'll need to make the function take only one argument.

```
from functools import partial
invoke = partial (invoke_query, connection)
for result in map (invoke, queries): 
    #...
```

But in simple cases there's no advantage.

Comment: I think you accidentally put in some sort of alternative bracket characters - those aren't normal brackets.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, sorry. I'm on my phone and have a Chinese keyboard. Didn't realize I don't have normal brackets

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't use `map` or list comprehensions for side effects.